# Render page from plugin controller

Tags: php, impresspages

Is it possible to render an existing page from my plugin controller?

Something like:

```
ipContent()->getPage($id)->render()
```

Comment: https://www.impresspages.org/docs/class-ip-widgetcontroller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to find out the published revision of that page. And then generate the content of it

https://www.impresspages.org/page-content-by-id